# How to send a hyperlink using query string method like `www.something.aspx?uniqueid=google+com`?

Tags: asp.net

I want to send `hyperlink` by attach it with `URL` with the help of query string method. For instance in a web page containing three links like

```
google.com 

yahoo.com

facbook.com
```

now  suppose user click on yahoo.com at this point i want to send it by attaching with url like
`www.something.aspx?uniqueid=google+com` ..........some thing like that

Comment: not sure i understand your question properly, but why cant just set the uri as 

www.something.aspx?uniqueid=google+com

on the hyperlink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="http://www.something.com/something.aspx?uniqueid=google.com" Text="http://www.google.com/"></asp:HyperLink>
```

This will display the text "http://www.google.com/" on the page, but the link itself will be via your "something.aspx" page.